# Cannot convert empty array of arrays to JSON with Swift 2

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift2

What is wrong with this piece of code (which was inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28325471/1789384) example)? It currently prints JSON string `"(<5b5d>, 4)"` instead of the expected `"[]"`.

```
var tags: [[String]] = []
// tags to be added later ...
do {
    let data = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(tags, options: [])
    let json = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    print("\(json)")
}
catch {
    fatalError("\(error)")
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer:** The creation of the JSON data is correct. The problem is in the
conversion of the data to a string, what you want is the `NSString` method:

```
let json = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
```

which produces the expected `[]`.

**Slightly longer answer:**
Your code

```
let json = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

calls the `String` init method

```
/// Initialize `self` with the textual representation of `instance`.
/// ...
init<T>(_ instance: T)
```

and the result is the textual representation of the *tuple*
`(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)`:

```
(<5b5d>, 4)
```

Actually you can call `String()` with arbitrary arguments

```
let s = String(foo: 1, bar: "baz")
print(s) // (1, "baz")
```

in Swift 2. This does not compile in Swift 1.2, so I am not sure if
this is intended or not. I have posted a question in the
Apple Developer Forums about that:

- [String init accepts arbitrary arguments](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/12906).

Comment: What a "bridge"! :) Thx.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. Anyway, you only convert JSON data to a string for debugging.

Comment: And I haven't found any guarantee anywhere that the JSON data would be UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: @gnasher729: It's not a guarantee, but https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-8.1 states: *"The default encoding is UTF-8, ..."*. – On the other hand, OP's original code now works as expected, because `String` has an `init?(data: NSData, encoding: NSStringEncoding)` method now.

Comment: @gnasher729: Also the documentation for `dataWithJSONObject` explicitly states: *"The resulting data is encoded in UTF-8."*