# what's the proper use of joinWithSeparator in Swift when I want to use "

Tags: ios, swift, mongodb, nsstring

In my `swift` ios app I have a [String] array and I want to build a string based on it. In my code I have:

```
var processedString: String = ""

processedString = "\(hashtags.joinWithSeparator("\", \""))"
```

then I upload it to my server with `alamofire`.

Currently on my server it creates an entry in mongoDB:

```
"hashtags" : [ "test\", \"one\", \"two" ],
```

I would like to get rid of `\` marks and leave only `"`. I tried to do:

```
processedString = "\(hashtags.joinWithSeparator(", "))"
```

but then on my server I have:

```
"hashtags" : [ "test, one, two" ],
```

and I need it as an array of strings:

```
"hashtags" : [ "test", "one", "two" ],
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You are going about this all wrong. Don't manually build JSON output from strings. Use `JSONSerialization` instead.

Comment: maddy can you give me some example of that?

Comment: Please search. There are countless examples of converting a dictionary/array into JSON.

Comment: @maddy so I followed this http://stackoverflow.com/a/35429117/3766930 answer and then in my `alamofire` after using `"hashtags": [processedHashtags]` I'm getting `hashtags =     (
        "[\n  \"tes\",\n  \"ges\",\n  \"gds\"\n]"
    );` which is weird for me, how can I parse it without `\n` and `\`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use hashtags.joinWithSeparator() for a whole bunch of reasons, not the least of which is it inserts the separator character between array values, not before and after them.

Instead use this Swift 3 sample code:

```
let hashtags = ["test", "one", "two"]
let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: hashtags, options: [])
let processedString = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))
```

(I left out much of the bullet proofing for the sake of clarity.)