# Convert Swift 3 Array to JSON

Tags: arrays, json

I have array of dictionary [[String:Any]] i want to convert it to JSON string. but i don't know how to start with it. I tried JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: array, options: .prettyPrinted) and i pass array to method but it show error. Any solution please comment below. Thank.

Comment: Could you include your code?

Comment: If this is a Swift question please add the relevant tag(s). Also, you should provide the specific error your attempt is showing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert array to JSON string in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28325268/convert-array-to-json-string-in-swift)

Answer (score 2):

Try as following code...

```
do {

    //Convert to Data
    let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionaryArray, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)

    //Do this for print data only otherwise skip
    if let JSONString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
       print(JSONString)
    }

    //In production, you usually want to try and cast as the root data structure. Here we are casting as a dictionary. If the root object is an array cast as [AnyObject].
    var json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? [String: AnyObject]


    } catch {
        print(error.description)
    }
```