# Access the JSONString in mapping using Swift ObjectMapper library

Tags: swift, realm, objectmapper

I would like to return the native JSON String to store in Realm, since Realm can't store collections of native objects.

Example JSON:
`{ "root": { "id":1, "name":"name", "array":["a", "b", "c"] }}`

```
func mapping(map:Map) {
  id <- map["id]
  name <- map["name"]
  array <- map["array"].JSONString  // array = "[\"a\", \"b\", \"c\"]"
}
```

Is this possible?

Same question on github https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper/issues/730

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, Realm can indeed [store collections of sub-objects](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#to-many-relationships).

```
class StringObject: Object {
    dynamic var string = ""
}

class Root: Object {
    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var name = ""
    let array = List<StringObject>()
}
```

Beyond that, if I understand ObjectMapper correctly, by the time `map["array"]` is already passed in `mapping`, it's already been converted from JSON to a Swift object. In which case, you'd need to [reserialize it back into JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28325268/convert-array-to-json-string-in-swift) yourself.