# Printing valid JSON with a Swift script

Tags: json, swift, ubuntu

I am attempting to print out in the command line the contents of a variable that holds a JSON object, like in the code:

```
#! /usr/bin/swift
import Glibc
import Foundation

let albert_op = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["ALBERT_OP"]!


if albert_op == "METADATA" {
    let metadata = [
        ["iid": "org.albert.extension.external/v2.0",
        "name": "Tomboy",
        "version": "0.1",
        "author": "Will Timpson",
        "dependencies": ["tomboy", "python-pydbus"],
        "trigger": "tb "]
    ]
    print(metadata))
}


exit(0)
```

However, that prints out:

```
[["trigger": "tb ", "name": "Tomboy", "iid": "org.albert.extension.external/v2.0", "dependencies": ["tomboy", "python-pydbus"], "version": "0.1", "author": "Will Timpson"]]
```

Which is not valid, I was expecting something like:

```
{"version": "0.1", "author": "Will Timpson", "iid": "org.albert.extension.external/v2.0", "trigger": "tb ", "dependencies": ["tomboy", "python-pydbus"], "name": "Tomboy"}
```

- How to achieve the proper result?

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28325268/convert-array-to-json-string-in-swift

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Two issues:

1. You don't have the structure you ultimately want. You have an array with one item in it, and that item is a dictionary. Based on your expected output, you seem to just want a dictionary. You can fix this by dropping the extra square brackets.
2. JSON is a serialization format. You don't have "a JSON object." You have data that you would like to serialize as JSON. You can do that with `JSONSerialization`.

Here's working code that produces the expected output:

```
#! /usr/bin/swift

import Foundation

// Drop the extra brackets, and use a type annotation
let metadata: [String: Any] = [
    "iid": "org.albert.extension.external/v2.0",
    "name": "Tomboy",
    "version": "0.1",
    "author": "Will Timpson",
    "dependencies": ["tomboy", "python-pydbus"],
    "trigger": "tb"
]

// Serialize to JSON
let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: metadata)

// Convert to a string and print
if let JSONString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
   print(JSONString)
}

// Output:
// {"iid":"org.albert.extension.external\/v2.0","name":"Tomboy","version":"0.1","dependencies":["tomboy","python-pydbus"],"author":"Will Timpson","trigger":"tb"}
```

Comment: Essentially, the conversion to a string could fail. I'm not sure that in practice this is an actual issue. You could use `let JSONString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!` instead to force unwrapping the value.

Answer (score 14):

Swift 4.2 Extension
Looked up @smarx solution a lot of times to print my JSON string.
Eventually ended up making an extension

```
extension Data
{
    func printJSON()
    {
        if let JSONString = String(data: self, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        {
            print(JSONString)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Swift 4:

If you want a quick dirty one liner just for example, checking the serialised JSON Data you are about to attach to a http request body then I use the following:

```
let json = NSString(data: myJsonObject, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
print(json)
```

It prints as clear JSON, no added slashes or anything!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using do {} catch { () } block, and before serialization do check if its a valid JSON object.

```
           do {

                    if let result = responseObj.result, JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(result) {

                        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: result)

                        // Convert to a string and print
                        if let JSONString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
                            print(JSONString)
                        }
                    }
                } catch {
                    ()
                }
```

Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using encodable entity, this JsonEncoder object will print that json.

```
let entity = RequestEntity(...)
do {
     if let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(entity) {
        if let JSONString = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
           print(JSONString)
        }
      }
   } 

/// Without slash in jsonString:
extension Encodable {
    func encodeToJSONString() -> String? {
        do {
            let encoder = JSONEncoder()
            encoder.outputFormatting = .withoutEscapingSlashes
            let data = try encoder.encode(self)
            return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I guess, I solved this in a very easy way. It shows well formatted json from object in **xcode** logcat.

```
let jsonString = object.toJSONString(prettyPrint: true)
print(jsonString as AnyObject)
```

Comment: This is a function of ObjectMapper library and the question is unrelated to the object mapper here.