# How to convert Dictionary with Array to String and back?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

How can I convert Dictionary with array to string and back?

```
["http://www.somehost.com": 
    [
        "some_name",
        "some_pass",
        "date_modification",
        "other_stuff"
    ]
]

// convert it to string

"skdjfsfjkhjsdfjh:sdlfksdfkj / sdlkfjsdfkj / sldkfsdkjfkjh / skjdfsdjhsd"

// convert string back to ["host": ["name","pass","date","other_stuff"]
```

Can I use JSON for it?

Comment: If you want to use JSON, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28325268/convert-array-to-json-string-in-swift/34055555).

Comment: Can you please post a valid example. Your original dictionary, your string, and your new dictionary have no data in common so it is not clear at all what you are trying to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made one slight tweak to the string, as the dictionary key (`http://www.somehost.com`) contains the separator you're trying to use (`:`), so it makes decoding rather fiddly.

Since it's easy to map a `Dictionary` to a `(key, value)` tuple, the encoding functions are as simple as:

```
func encode(_ entry: (key: String, value: [String]), keySeparator: String, arraySeparator: String) -> String
{
    return entry.key + keySeparator + encode(entry.value, separator: arraySeparator)
}

func encode(_ array: [String], separator: String) -> String
{
    return array.joined(separator: separator)
}
```

Decoding can then simply be:

```
func decode(_ strings: [String], keySeparator: String, arraySeparator: String) -> [String:[String]]
{
    return strings.reduce([String:[String]]())
    {
        var dict = $0
        guard let decoded = decode($1, keySeparator: keySeparator, arraySeparator: arraySeparator)
            else { return $0 }

        dict[decoded.key] = decoded.value
        return dict
    }
}

func decode(_ string: String, keySeparator: String, arraySeparator: String) -> (key: String, value: [String])?
{
    let split = string.components(separatedBy: keySeparator)

    guard split.count == 2 else { return nil }

    let key = split[0]
    let value = decodeValues(split[1], separator: arraySeparator)
    return (key, value)
}

func decodeValues(_ string: String, separator: String) -> [String]
{
    return string.components(separatedBy: separator)
}
```

Finally, running everything can be done with:

```
let dict = ["http://www.somehost.com":
    [
        "some_name",
        "some_pass",
        "date_modification",
        "other_stuff"
    ]
]

let keySeparator = "::"
let arraySeparator = " / "

let encoded = dict.map { encode($0, keySeparator: keySeparator, arraySeparator: arraySeparator) }
print(encoded) // ["http://www.somehost.com::some_name / some_pass / date_modification / other_stuff"]

let decoded = decode(encoded, keySeparator: keySeparator, arraySeparator: arraySeparator)
print (decoded) // ["http://www.somehost.com": ["some_name", "some_pass", "date_modification", "other_stuff"]]
```

This definite could be neatened up with extensions, but this will get you 80% of the way there.

Comment: you made my day, dude!

Comment: I wonder whats wrong with using JSONSerialization API instead of trying to implement your own

Comment: i was mess with all i was thinking that is possible to do with json but i'm beginner and learning, just fully mess with all.

Comment: Note that if any element of the array value of any dictionary key contains "::" it would be enough to make it return an empty dictionary.