# Create JSON API Request

Tags: json, swift, rest, api

I'm trying to make a JSON data for my API request, see example below:

[image]

```
    var itemsArray = [String:AnyObject]()
    var itemDictionary: [String: Any] = ["employee":"Max Mustermann", "table":"Tisch X"]

    for item in items{

            let item = item as! Items
            itemsArray = ["name": item.name as AnyObject, "quantity": String(item.count) as AnyObject]
        }
        itemDictionary["items"] = itemsArray


    let jsonData = [itemDictionary]
    guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonData, options: []) else{
        return }
```

and that's my code for this but it doesn't work. 
I don't know what is wrong with this code.

I hope anyone can help me. That's the last step to finish my project.

Comment: look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28325268/convert-array-to-json-string-in-swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 do {

let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions()) as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>

} 
catch 
{
     return NSError(domain: "\(error)" , code: 1, userInfo: nil)
}
```